# How to find the first few terms of the taylor expansion of $\sqrt[5]{t} \int \frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{t}} (1-t)^{-\frac{1}{5}} \, dt$?

Tags: calculus

When plugged into wolfram alpha, it gives you this:
$$\frac{5 t}{4}+\frac{t^2}{9}+\frac{3 t^3}{70}+\frac{11 t^4}{475}+\frac{11 t^5}{750}+...$$

How can we get this taylor series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain it by computing the first couple of terms of the Taylor series of $(1-t)^{-\frac{1}{5}}$. 
Note that there is a general formula for $(1+x)^\alpha$ with $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: General formula is given by the extended binomial theorem.